# Stop scrolling for a content in a scrollviewer

Tags: wpf, silverlight, c#-4.0, windows-8

Is it possible to stop scrolling for a content in a scrollviewer? e.g.

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock /> <!-- I want not to scroll this item when rest is scrolling -->
        <!-- other controls -->
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Placing the element outside scrollviewer is not considered.

Comment: Why don't you explain *what* you're trying to achieve - cause from the looks of it you're not going in the right direction...

Comment: I want to get a look and feel of windows 8 travel apps like scrolling effect in wpf

Comment: Ok, and why can't the textblock be outside of the scrollviewer?

Comment: Cause after some scrolling the textblock also need to scroll.

Comment: You can nest one ScrollViewer into another.

Answer (score 1):

If this is in a desktop app using WPF probably the best place to do it would be by overriding the [ArrangeOverride](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.arrangeoverride.aspx) method of ScrollViewer. In this case I would recommend creating your own custom attached property like **ScrollHoldOffset** and assigning that to the TextBox. Then, in the override, you could check each control to see if it has this property set. If it does, the control should be held in place instead of scrolled until the scroll has gone beyond a certain threshold (**ScrollHoldOffset**).

If this is a Windows Store app it's going to be a lot more difficult because ScrollViewer is sealed and therefore can't be inherited from nor can the ArrangeOverride method be overridden. It may be possible to write some code to "undo" the scroll whenever the scroll position changes. I'd start from [this example](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/3703/how-to-detect-the-scrollbar-has-changed-in-a-scrollviewer-in.aspx) that shows you how to subscribe to the scroll bar position changed event. Then, you could change the RenderTransform to offset the scroll.

Sorry I don't have time today to code this up, so it's going to have to be in theory instead of practice. I hope it helps.

Dev support, design support and more awesome goodness on the way: http://bit.ly/winappsupport

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do this:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <TextBlock /> 
    <ScrollViewer>
        <Grid>
            <!-- other controls -->
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</ScrollViewer>
```