# WPF TextBox Styling - Disable scrolling?

Tags: c#, wpf

it's my first question here so be gentle haha

I am using a WPF TextBox Element to enter some user information, in this example it's a username.
My problem with this is that I am able to scroll within the TextBox which I don't want, as it just looks terrible even if it is just a bit.

So I am looking for an option to turn the scrolling off. As you can see I am using a ScrollViewer, as the documentation suggests but if there are any other options for styling the TextBox I am more then willing to try :D
Thanks in advance.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}"
       x:Key="textBox1">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Border CornerRadius="16"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ScrollViewer Margin="10,7.5"
                                  x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>

                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>

        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
```

=> This is the Style of the TextBox in a RessourceDic.

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <Grid Height="250"/>
        

        <TextBlock x:Name="Error"
                   FontSize="14"
                   Foreground="DarkRed"
                   FontWeight="Bold"
                   Margin="5"
                   TextWrapping="Wrap"/>

        <TextBlock Text="Benutzername" Margin="15,0,0,10" FontSize="20"/>
        <TextBox Margin="0,0,20,0"
                 Background="#F2E3D5"
                 x:Name="Username"
                 Style="{StaticResource textBox1}"
                 Width="230"
                 Height="35"
                 FontSize="21">
           
        </TextBox>
        <TextBlock Text="Passwort" Margin="15,20,0,10" FontSize="20"/>
        <PasswordBox Margin="0,0,20,0"
                     Background="#F2E3D5"
                     x:Name="Password"
                     Style="{StaticResource passwordBox1}"
                     FontSize="21">

        </PasswordBox>

        <Button x:Name="LogIn" Height="40" Width="120" Style="{StaticResource LogInBTN}" Foreground="Black" Margin="0,30,0,0" Click="LogInBTN_Click">

            <Button.Content>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="images/user.png" Height="25" Width="25" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Einloggen" Margin="10,2,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button.Content>

        </Button>

        <TextBlock Margin="0,20,0,0" Height="20" Width="250" Text="X - Passwort nicht korrekt" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="16" Foreground="Red" Visibility="Hidden"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

=> This is the Stackpanel where I use the TextBox.

Comment: idk what documentation and what it suggests but none of your xaml makes no sense. whats the original task at hand? show the code from where the observed behaviour started to deviate from what you need and write what you need/expect

Comment: You don't want to scroll. But you put a scrollviewer in your template? You realise what a SCROLL viewer does?

Comment: @BoppityBop I want a TextBox to enter a Username that is styled in the way the above code shows. There is nothing more to it. 

The user should enter his username and be done. But while he is typing he can scroll within the small Box, I don't want that.

The documentation I read was this one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/textbox-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

I edited the XAML so it makes a bit more sens I hope.

Comment: @Andy yes I know what a SCROLLVIEWER does, but this one of only two Elements to be named PART_ContentHost as far as I am concerned. So I am pretty much limited there aren't I ?

Here the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/textbox-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stop scrolling for a content in a scrollviewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14938086/stop-scrolling-for-a-content-in-a-scrollviewer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as workaround, without overriding ScrollViewer:

```
<TextBox Height="30" Width="50">
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                                <Decorator x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```